# How to grep in dataset on hdfs using hadoop streaming

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I have a huge data set lying in hdfs and I want to grep some terms out of it. What is the haddop streaming command for same ?
(Please see I don;t want to use PIG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command :-

hadoop jar  {path_to_jar}/hadoop-streaming.jar   -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default   -Dstream.non.zero.exit.is.failure=false -Dmapred.job.name="grepper" -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 -input /tmp/{input_path}   -output /tmp/{output_path}   -mapper 'grep searchTerm'

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  Just curious what does -Dstream.non.zero.exit.is.failure=false did here ?

Comment: Without this mappers will fail wherever this search term is not found